# My javascript is only working for the first class name

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/joel081112/fctL5z2u/15/

I'm not sure how to fix it since I'm new to JavaScript but I've tried some for-each statements and got nowhere. Here is a fiddle with 3 elements with the class-name `bodymovianim` but only the first element is appearing. How can I alter this js to show it in each div?

```
let iconMenu = document.querySelector('.bodymovinanim');

    let animationMenu = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
            container: iconMenu,
            renderer: 'svg',
            loop: false,
            autoplay: false,
            path: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thesvbd/Lottie-examples/master/assets/animations/menu.json"
    });

    var directionMenu = 1;
      iconMenu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      animationMenu.setDirection(directionMenu);
      animationMenu.play();
      directionMenu = -directionMenu;
    });
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` will always return the first matched element only. You want `.querySelectorAll()` or `.getElementsByClassName()` instead. But check their return values.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I tried those but they werent showing up at all

Comment: @Dai the names are all bodymoviani, see in the jsfiddle

Comment: I assume [this is what you are trying to do](https://jsbin.com/kabokopime/1/edit?js,output)?

Comment: @Yousaf Yes! That is exactly it. Thank you

Comment: @Yousaf Just so you know the solution was good apart from the fact the `var directionMenu` had to be inside the `foreach` and above the event handler code line. Thank you for the solution though